# Datepicker to show previous month dates in single table view

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am trying to show last 35 days from the current day in a datepicker with a single table view. Rest of the dates should not be visible.
For example for 25-July-2014 the datepicker should be something like this.

```
 SUN MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT

                          21
  22  23  24  25  26  27  28
  29  30   1   2   3   4   5
   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
  13  14  15  16  17  18  19
  20  21  22  23  24  25
```

<strike>Had written Java Code [here](http://ideone.com/T8oIvM).</strike>

I tried increasing the numRows in jquery-ui.js to 6, but it only adds rows with dates of next month and not of previous month, like this:

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V2CB8/3/)

Please help. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it. Thanks Palpatim for the idea of defaultDate.

Datepicker function:

```
$(function() {    
   $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    minDate:"-34",
    defaultDate: "-34d",
    maxDate:"0",
    showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    onSelect: function(date) {
           alert(date);
        }
   });  
});
```

Made two changes in jquery-ui.js

1. Increased 'numRows' to 12.
2. Commented updateDatePicker to prevent any reset of datepicker.

   numRows = 12;

   //this._updateDatepicker(inst);

Then removed the unwanted rows as follows:

```
    function doTheMagic(){
        $tr=$(".ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr");
        for(i=0;i<$tr.length;i++){

              $f=0;
              $($tr[i]).find("td").each(function(f){
              if($(this).attr("class").indexOf("disabled")<0)
                {
                  $f=1;
                  return false;
                }
                });

              if($f==0)
                $($tr[i]).remove();


        }

        $("td[class=' ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled '], td[class=' ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled '], td[class=' ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled '], td[class=' ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled ']").each(
              function(){$(this).empty();}
            );
    }
```

Just how I wanted:

[image]

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naiveAlgorist/L6k5U/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the `defaultDate` option:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/kwcLC/1/)

```
$(function () {
    var $datePicker = $("#datepicker");
    $datePicker.datepicker({
        defaultDate: "-34d",
        minDate: "-34",
        maxDate: "0",
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        onSelect: function (date) {
            alert(date + " selected");
        }
    });
    alert($datePicker.datepicker("getDate"));
});
```

Which renders:

> [image: Screenshot of Date Picker defaulting to -34d]